# Autodesk Forge - Extension button to get data from external SQL database

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, autodesk-forge

I am trying to connect my Forge app to a sql database, but I have no idea how to do that. I am new to forge and web development, so I don't know how to look for the best approach to solve this.
I found a code that does exactly what I want, that is getting the data from a specific table of my database, but I'm not able to put this code inside my forge app, mainly because it uses a require() function and I can't put it inside my extension button.
By the way, I'm trying to make a button in my extension where I click, it access my database and get data from it.
Would be really nice if someone could help me with this silly doubt that probably already has a solution in the internet and I'm not able to find it.
Sorry in advance if it's too obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is more related to web development than Forge.
Your app should be made of 2 parts : the **frontend** (html/css/js) and a **backend** (probably nodejs as you tagged it).
Your frontend should not access the database directly. This is the job of your **backend**.

In your **backend**, add a library to access your **database** such as [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org) (if you are working with NodeJS). Then you will do a request from your **frontend** to your **backend** to get the data from the database.
You probably have something working like that for your Forge Access Token, depending on what you use to start your development.

Comment: Hi AlexAR, perfect answer, but I didn't know how to do that, so I looked for the Forge team and they helped me. Thank you for your answer!